# Declared struct in .h and enum in .c file

Tags: c, enums

I have declared a struct with an enum type. Since it's a member in .h and the enum in .c file, where I use the enum in my code.

Is this legal to do, or will this cause compilation issues?

```
// in test.h 
typedef struct {
   eState state;    

} TEST;

// in test.c
#include "test.h"

typedef enum {
    DEFAULT,
    FAST 

} eState;
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it?

Comment: No it won't, you need to add forward declaration in test.h before the typedef struct

Comment: Maybe if you add enum eState before in your test.h

Answer (score -1):

You have three options:

1. Move enum declaration to the `.h` file (it has to be before your struct declaration).
2. Or absolutely ridiculous and stupid (you will have to declare the enum the same way in every file you include your `.h` file) but legal from the language point of view

   ```
   // in test.c
   typedef enum {
       DEFAULT,
       FAST 
   } eState;

   #include "test.h"
   ```
3. You can also move the struct declaration to the `.c` file.

Comment: While option 2 is legal --- it only works in test.h is only included in test.c.  Include it in any other file, and it fails.  Which negates the purpose of having it in a header file to start with.

Comment: @James Curran `or absolutely ridiculous but legal from the language point of view` - and you have commented it.

Comment: @PeterJ I think it is implied that OP will use the header file from other .c files too, without doing this in each one, so it would not be legal

Comment: @James Curran `absolutely ridiculous and stupid but legal from the language point of view` happy? Any stronger? - but I do not want to be banned

Comment: @M.M: I don’t think that’s implied, given that the definition is obviously required and only provided in `test.c`.

Comment: Perhaps a fourth option would be to place the `enum` definition in yet another `.h` file to be `#include`d in `test.h`, and wherever else it may be needed.

Comment: @David Bowling good idea 10 lines of code 3 files. Maybe keywords or brackets in the separate .h files.

Comment: @Ryan why would you use a .h file if you didn't intend it to be included from multiple .c files ?

Comment: @M.M: Could include it with different definitions of `eState`. I don’t know. That doesn’t address my original question of why you would write an .h file that depended on the contents of the .c file including it anyway.

Comment: @PeterJ Dude, chill....  You said it was a bad idea.  I explained WHY it was a bad idea.

Comment: @James Curran don't you nitpick a bit? Interesting why was I DVted?